# Не печатать заголовок в diff

Tags: diff

Есть два файла: `./a/config` и `./b/config`.
Хочется вывести разницу между ними в таком формате:

```diff
- name = foo
+ name = bar
```

Самое близкое, чего смог достичь с помощью `diff`, это такое:

```sh
$ diff -U 0 ./a/gitconfig ./b/gitconfig
```

```diff
--- ./a/gitconfig   2019-09-16 23:12:07.736955089 +0300
+++ ./b/gitconfig   2019-09-16 23:12:07.580958471 +0300
@@ -19 +19 @@
- name = foo
+ name = bar
```

Есть ли у `diff` флаг, чтобы не печатать заголовок? Или
только фильтровать `grep`'ом?

Comment: `| tail -n +4` чтобы начать печатать с четвёртой строки?

Comment: @andreymal Не получится, ибо каждый _chunk_ будет со своим собственным заголовком, который надо удалить.

Comment: Точно, забыл о них

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге пришёл к такому варианту:

```sh
$ diff ./a/gitconfig ./b/gitconfig | sed '/^[[:digit:]]/d; /^-/d; s/^</-/; s/^>/+/'
```

```
- name = foo
+ name = bar
```